# How can i save more than one data in Codable (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, data-structures, codable

I use the Codable protocol with JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder.

But when I save the data, only the last value is saved, but I need to save more than one.

If I add three cards, I can only see the last one.

Example:

**I add card:**

```
        CName: Test1, BarCode: 12345, CardNBR: 12345

        CName: Test2, BarCode: 1234567, CardNBR: 1234567

        CName: Test3, BarCode: 123456789, CardNBR: 123456789
```

in the end I see only: **CName: Test3, BarCode: 123456789, CardNBR: 123456789**

**How can i save more than one data?**

```
struct Entity : Codable  {

   var cname: String
   var barcode: String
   var cardnbr: String
}
```

**Save**

```
let arr = Entity(cname: CompanyName, barcode: BarCodeField, cardnbr: CardNumber)

do {
   let data  = try JSONEncoder().encode(all)
   UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "Key")
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

**Load**

```
do {
   let content = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Key")
   let saved = try JSONDecoder().decode([Entity].self, from: content!)
   print(saved)
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

**NEW**

```
let arr = Entity(cname: CompanyName, barcode: BarCodeField, cardnbr: CardNumber)

        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            var jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(arr)
            let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
            print("JSON String : " + jsonString!)

            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let upMovie = try jsonDecoder.decode(Entity.self, from: jsonData)
            print("upMovie : \(upMovie)")
            print("cname : \(arr.cname)")
            print("barcode : \(arr.barcode)")
            print("cardnbr : \(arr.cardnbr)")
            entities.append(Entity(cname: arr.cname, barcode: arr.barcode, cardnbr: arr.cardnbr))
            print(entities)
        }
        catch {
        }
```

Comment: Your `let all = []` line only creates a single instance of `Entity`. You do not show code for making separate instances and adding them to an array.

Comment: First of all please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter. `all` contains only one item when being saved.

Comment: Hello,

I think this tutorial will help you what you want please visit the link.
http://ashishkakkad.com/2017/06/use-codable-coding-key-jsonencoder-jsondecoder-swift-4/

Comment: @hardikvyas To use the tutorial, I still save only the last value JSON String : {"cname":"Test3","barcode":"123456789","cardnbr":"123456789"}

Comment: @hardikvyas I have array **var entities = [Entity]()**  Im need make this for adding data to this array?: entities.append(Entity(cname: arr.cname, barcode: arr.barcode, cardnbr: arr.cardnbr))

Comment: @B2Fq Please ask question on that tutorial may be that person help you i have very basic idea about this so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you save new

```
let arr = Entity(cname: CompanyName, barcode: BarCodeField, cardnbr: CardNumber)
```

contains only one Entity, thats the reason you are getting only last Entity

Solution: before save you must add last saved array as well.
Assume an Entity

```
let aEntity = Entity(CName: "Test1", BarCode: "12345", CardNBR: "12345")
```

and to save it

```
if var all :[Entity] = loadData() {
    all.append(aEntity)
    saveData(allData: all)
}else {
    saveData(allData: [aEntity])
}
```

add following functions in class

```
func saveData(allData:[Entity]) {
    do {
        let data  = try JSONEncoder().encode(allData)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "Key")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
func loadData() -> [Entity]?{
    do {
        if let content = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Key") {
            let saved :[Entity] = try JSONDecoder().decode([Entity].self, from: content)
            print(saved)
            return saved
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: When i add data to array: **entities.append(Entity(cname: arr.cname, barcode: arr.barcode, cardnbr: arr.cardnbr))**   As a result, my array:   **[CardHolder.Entity(cname: "Test", barcode: "1234", cardnbr: "1234"), CardHolder.Entity(cname: "Hdhdhd", barcode: "646464", cardnbr: "499494")]**

Comment: You should conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for function and variable names. Your functions should be called `loadData` and `saveData`.